What is some antonym of shortchange?
What is some antonym of shortchange? I can't find any at https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/shortchange. There doesn't seem to be word "longchange".

Do you mean literally or figuratively?  Do you mean "pay the right amount of change" or "pay more than the right amount of change"?  Note that while adjectives generally have a clear "opposite" sense, words like nouns and verbs often don't have opposites.  What is the antonym of "eat"?  What is the antonym of "apple"?

@JamesK Given the mention of the nonexistent but unambiguous longchange, I’d say the intended meaning is definitely ‘give more in change than is due’, not ‘give the correct change’.

@JanusBahsJacquet "vomit" and "orange" (as in "comparing apples and oranges"). Too easy :)

@Barmar Was that meant for James?

@JanusBahsJacquet Yes, auto-complete fail.

I think "give the wrong change" or more specifically "give too much change" would be usual.

Does your language have such a word? If so what happens when you try translating it in an online dictionary? If not, why do you think English has such a word?

What is the opposite of to commit murder? or to cheat someone? or to commit larceny?

Not every word has a clear antonym. For some words, it's not clear what the opposite would be. Like what is the opposite of "horse"? In this case, presumably the opposite would be a word meaning that the person was given too much change. I'm not aware of any such word. You have to use a phrase, like, "They gave me too much change."

Good point - "nounds don't have antonyms"

@Criggie And not all adjectives have antonyms. Like sure, the opposite of "big" is "small". But what's the antonym of "yellow"? Or of "French"? Or "itchy"? I suppose you could always say, "not that", like "not French". But that's not really a category in itself, just saying it's not in the first category.

nounds --> nouns    (silly 5 minute edit limit)

@Criggie And here I was thinking that a "nound" must be a circular person, place or thing ...

Some related but imperfect antonyms: literally, overpay; figuratively, go the extra mile, be more than fair, go above and beyond.
As others have said, none of these are quite antonyms. "Overpay" does not suggest intent whereas "shortchange" does. And none of the others share quite the context of "shortchange", which also suggests that the action is not disclosed till it's too late.
Incidentally, this actually happened to me once with a newcomer to Canada working at a pizza parlour. I owed $5.10 and had exact change. He would not accept the dime. "Oh, no!" he protested. "One doesn't worry about nickels and dimes, does one?" In the end I simply couldn't give it to him. (Perhaps he thought it would be insulting, as if to give it to him would mean accusing him of having demanded it.)
This was so unusual that I told people about it. There is no one word in English to describe this exchange. He didn't overpay, because it wasn't him giving the money. He let me underpay — and those three words are the shortest way I can think of to say it.

Incidentally, note that "shortchange" does not have to be in the context of giving change. It can mean "give less than one was supposed to give in an exchange", or, a little more precisely, "cause someone to get less than they were supposed to receive in an exchange". For example, once when we were doing our annual handing-down of sibling clothes, I got less from my older brother than I gave to my younger brother. Joking (because there was no real reason to expect to get the same amount as one gave), we agreed that I had been "shortchanged". I got less than I might have had a right to. (It helped the joke that among the items I'd given away were shorts. :))

Overpay seems specifically an "accidental" thing whereas shortchanging someone  could be either intentional or accidental.   tip could be an intentional overpayment, but that has implications of payment-for-service like Americans do.   rounding is also a slight overpayment but only up to the next denomination of currency.

@Criggie Overpay is almost never intentional. It usually has the same meaning as overpriced but as a verb instead

Overpaying is the same as shortchanging, not the opposite. If I buy something that costs $16, pay with a $20 bill and get $3 back, I’ve been shortchanged, which means I’ve overpaid. If I get $5 back, I’ve underpaid and have been [antonym the asker is looking for – which I would instinctively call ‘overchanged’].

@JanusBahsJacquet By reversing the subject, of course you get a synonym instead of an antonym. If you were to keep the point of view the same it would be an antonym. Same action, opposite sides of the table. // But more importantly, as the others have said, it's not a perfect antonym since it doesn't suggest intent as "shortchange" does.

@slebetman I frequently round up and say "Keep the change", which is intentional overpaying.

@Barmar Nice; that's a closer if longer equivalent to "shortchange" than "overpay" is.

Although shortchange is something the vendor does, while overpay is something the customer does.

@Barmar Agreed that this is what makes it not a great antonym, and I think what makes Janus doubtful. Switching POV feels like a less usual way to derive an antonym than switching the action performed. :)
